# constraints are reapplied when timer is running and changes label text

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, multithreading

I'm working on a swift camera app and trying to solve the following problem.
My camera app, which allows taking a video, can change the camera focus and exposure when a user taps somewhere on the screen. Like the default iPhone camera app, I displayed the yellow square to show where the user tapped. I can see exactly where the user tapped unless triggering the timer function and updating the total video length on the screen.
Here is the image of the camera app.

[image]

As you can see there is a yellow square and that was the point I tapped on the screen.

[image]

However, when the timer counts up (in this case, 19 sec to 20sec) and updates the text of total video length, the yellow square moves back to the center of the screen. Since I put the yellow square at the center of the screen on my storyboard, I guess when the timer counts up and updates the label text, it also refreshing the yellow square, UIView, so displaying at the center of the screen (probably?).

So if I'm correct, how can I display the yellow square at the user tapped location regardless of the timer function, which updates UIlabel for every second?

Here is the code.

```
final class ViewController: UIViewController {

    private var pointOfInterestHalfCompletedWorkItem: DispatchWorkItem?
    @IBOutlet weak var pointOfInterestView: UIView!
    @IBOutlet weak var time: UILabel!
    var counter = 0
    var timer = Timer()
    
    override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
        pointOfInterestView.layer.borderWidth = 1
        pointOfInterestView.layer.borderColor = UIColor.systemYellow.cgColor
    }
    
    @objc func startTimer() {
        timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 1.0, target: self, selector: #selector(timerAction), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
    }
    
    @objc func timerAction() {
        counter += 1
        secondsToHoursMinutesSeconds(seconds: counter)
    }
    
    func secondsToHoursMinutesSeconds (seconds: Int) {

        // format seconds
        time.text = "\(strHour):\(strMin):\(strSec)"
    }

    override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
        let focusPoint = touches.first!.location(in: lfView)     
        showPointOfInterestViewAtPoint(point: focusPoint)
    }
       
    
    func showPointOfInterestViewAtPoint(point: CGPoint) {
        
        print("point is here \(point)")
          
        pointOfInterestHalfCompletedWorkItem = nil
        pointOfInterestComplatedWorkItem = nil
        pointOfInterestView.center = point
        
        
        pointOfInterestView.transform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: 1.5, y: 1.5)
        let animation = UIViewPropertyAnimator(duration: 0.3, curve: .easeInOut) {
            self.pointOfInterestView.transform = .identity
            self.pointOfInterestView.alpha = 1
        }
        animation.startAnimation()
        
        let pointOfInterestHalfCompletedWorkItem = DispatchWorkItem { [weak self] in
            guard let self = self else { return }
            let animation = UIViewPropertyAnimator(duration: 0.3, curve: .easeInOut) {
                self.pointOfInterestView.alpha = 0.5
            }
            animation.startAnimation()
        }
                                                           
        DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 2, execute: pointOfInterestHalfCompletedWorkItem)
        self.pointOfInterestHalfCompletedWorkItem = pointOfInterestHalfCompletedWorkItem
        
    }
    
}
```

Since I thought it's a threading issue, I tried to change the label text & to show the yellow square in the main thread by writing DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter, but it didn't work. Also, I was not sure if it becomes serial queue or concurrent queue if I perform both

1. loop the timer function and constantly updating label text
2. detect UI touch event and show yellow square

Since UI updates are performed in the main thread, I guess I need to figure out a way to share the main thread for the timer function and user touch event...

If someone knows a clue to solve this problem, please let me know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It isn't a threading issue.  It is an auto layout issue.

Presumably you have positioned the yellow square view in your storyboard using constraints.

You are then modifying the yellow square's `frame` directly by modifying the `center` property; this has no effect on the constraints that are applied to the view.  As soon as the next auto layout pass runs (triggered by the text changing, for example) the constraints are reapplied and the yellow square jumps back to where your constraints say it should be.

You have a couple of options;

1. Compute the destination point offset from the center of the view and then apply those offsets to the `constant` property of your two centering constraints
2. Add the yellow view programatically and position it by setting its frame directly.  You can then adjust the frame by modifying `center` as you do now.

Comment: Thank you so much for giving me a detailed explanation. Yes, I've positioned the square using constraints. I applied your second suggestion and it works now.